# Popup login Cakephp 3

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I can do login function if I make a a button in the home.ctp which link to login.ctp.
However, if the login input is in home.ctp, I cant make it work.
Login function in UsersController:

```
public function beforeFilter(Event $event)
{
    parent::beforeFilter($event);
    // Allow users to register and logout.
    // You should not add the "login" action to allow list. Doing so would
    // cause problems with normal functioning of AuthComponent.
    $this->Auth->allow(['add', 'logout', 'register']);
}

public function login()
{
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $user = $this->Auth->identify();
        if ($user) {
            $this->Auth->setUser($user);
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
        }
        $this->Flash->error(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
    }
    $this->render('Pages/home');
}
```

In home.ctp, I use login modal:

```
<!-- Login Modal -->  
<div class="modal fade" id="login-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">                      
    <div class="modal-body">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
      <h4>Login or Register</h4>
      <!-- form class="aa-login-form" action="" -->
      <?= $this->Form->create(null, ['class' => 'aa-login-form']); ?>
        <label for="">Email address<span>*</span></label>
        <?= $this->Form->input('email', ['type' => 'text', 'placeholder' => 'Email', 'label' => '', 'required' => false]); ?>
        <!-- input type="text" placeholder="Username or email" -->
        <label for="">Password<span>*</span></label>
        <?= $this->Form->input('passwords', ['type' => 'text', 'placeholder' => 'password', 'label' => '', 'required' => false]); ?>
        <!-- input type="password" placeholder="Password" -->
        <!-- button class="aa-browse-btn" type="submit">Login</button -->
        <?= $this->Form->button('Submit', ['class' => 'aa-browse-btn']); ?> 
        <label for="rememberme" class="rememberme"><input type="checkbox" id="rememberme"> Remember me </label>
        <p class="aa-lost-password"><a href="#">Lost your password?</a></p>
        <div class="aa-register-now">
          Don't have an account?<a href='<?= $this->Url->build(['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'register']); ?>'>Register now!</a>
        </div>
      </form>
      <?= $this->Flash->render(); ?>
    </div>                        
  </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
</div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
```

I am just not sure how to make login work when login input is provided in the home page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it seems that you did not set the action of the form. This way the data are sent to the home page and not to the login action.

```
echo $this->Form->create('User', 
[
    'class' => 'aa-login-form',
    'url' => ['controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login']
]);
```

see the [manual](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#setting-a-url-for-the-form) for reference

Comment: THank you for your help. I am new to cakephp so not really understand the code structure through. This help alot.